# How to convert LS_COLORS for Linux into LSCOLORS for BSD?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, ls, bsd

I've attemped using a `LSCOLORS` (BSD) [generator](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to convert the below `LS_COLORS` (Linux) to a format accepted by BSD.

Having read `man ls` on BSD, I don't think it has any support for specific file extensions (e.g. `*.tgz=01;31`), so I consider only the following `LS_COLORS` components:

`di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33;40:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43`

which has the equivalent `LSCOLORS` form: `exfxcxdabxegedabagacad`.

Now my problem with the concrete `LS_COLORS` below is that I  don't know how to represent e.g. `pi=40;33` in `LSCOLORS` form. In particular, the generator don't let me chose a value of `40` before the first semicolon (`40;33`)?

`LS_COLORS` (Debian 9):

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ dircolors
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html):

```
           a     black
           b     red
           c     green
           d     brown
           e     blue
           f     magenta
           g     cyan
           h     light grey
           A     bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
           B     bold red
           C     bold green
           D     bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
           E     bold blue
           F     bold magenta
           G     bold cyan
           H     bold light grey; looks like bright white
           x     default foreground or background
```

the requested `pi=40;33` is ***black*** background and ***brown*** foreground.  That is represented in `LSCOLORS` by the pair **`ad`**:

```
           a     black
           d     brown
```

There are no semicolons in `LSCOLORS`.  Those semicolons in `LS_COLORS` are used as parameter-separators in the escape sequences used for setting the colors (with a few hard-coded assumptions).  The two-digit values for colors are used in the SGR (select graphic rendition) [control sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-3-0.1E59).

Regarding the behavior of the *generator*, that's a JavaScript file which has this chunk:

```
// Linux LS_COLORS has different codes for foreground/background colors :/
if (i % 2 === 0) {
  // If bold, add bold thingy
  if (color === color.toUpperCase()) {
    linuxColorString += "1;";
    color = color.toLowerCase();
  }
```

That's apparently intended for the Linux console (mapping A-H to the *bold* form of a-h), but will work with some other terminals such as xterm, described in the [boldColors](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:boldColors) resource

```
   boldColors (class ColorMode)
           Specifies whether to combine bold attribute with colors like
           the IBM PC, i.e., map colors 0 through 7 to colors 8 through
           15.  These normally are the brighter versions of the first 8
           colors, hence bold.  The default is "true".
```

However (overlooked in `console_codes(4)`, [current](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) and [older](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502053155/https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)), Linux console has provided a way to set up 16 colors for both foreground (using bold, a "1" in SGR) and background (using blink, i.e., "5").  The [`linux-16color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-16color) terminal description uses that feature.  GNU ls doesn't use terminal descriptions; nor does that generator.  But the generator assumes that bold will make brighter versions (codes 8-15) from the ANSI colors (0-7).

Comment: Thank you. But why does the generator I’m linking too use the value `30;` for a black foreground?

Comment: In particular, `aD` equals `di=30;1;43` for LS_COLOR according to the generator. That doesn’t look like `pi=40;33`?

Comment: sorry - I had those interchanged.

Comment: You mean `40;33` is a brown background with a black foreground? Do you know why the  `1;` in `di=30;1;43` is showing up in the output of the generator, when no `1;`'s are present Debian's `LS_COLORS`?